# Download a binary file using Python requests module

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, urllib2

I need to download a file from an external source, I am using Basic authentication to login to the URL

```
import requests
response = requests.get('<external url', auth=('<username>', '<password>'))
data = response.json()
html = data['list'][0]['attachments'][0]['url']
print (html)
data = requests.get('<API URL to download the attachment>', auth=('<username>', '<password>'), stream=True)
print (data.content)
```

I am getting below output

```
<url to download the binary data> 
\x00\x00\x13\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f\xcb\x00\x00\x1e\x00\x1e\x00\xbe\x07\x00\x00.\xcf\x05\x00\x00\x00'
```

I am expecting the URL to download the word document within the same session.

Comment: So by the sounds of it the first step is fine (returns the url you want?). What you haven't done is extract the data from the second response.  "data = requests.get('<API URL to download the attachment>', stream=True)" should probably be something like "data = requests.get('<API URL to download the attachment>', stream=True).text" ? Try this and edit the question if it still doesn't work

Comment: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects and maybe also pass `auth` in the second request as well?

Comment: I recommend you re-read the Requests Quickstart documentation. To get _binary_ data from the returned Response object you need to access its [`.content`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content) attribute.

Comment: @PM 2Ring - I updated the code as per your comments and I am able to download the contents of the file. The requirement is to download the document as it is (in my case its a docx file - so to be specific I need to download the docx file without any ecoding OR decoding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to download a file directly  you can use  `shutil.copyfileobj()`:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj

You already are passing `stream=True` to `requests` which is what you need to get a file-like object back.  Just pass that as the source to `copyfileobj()`.

Answer (score 6):

Working solution

```
import requests
import shutil

response = requests.get('<url>', auth=('<username>', '<password>'))
data = response.json()
html = data['list'][0]['attachments'][0]['url']
print (html)
data = requests.get('<url>', auth=('<username>', '<password>'), stream=True)
with open("C:/myfile.docx", 'wb') as f:
    data.raw.decode_content = True
    shutil.copyfileobj(data.raw, f)
```

I am able to download the file as it is.