# How to download video from S3 using python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have the following algorithm

```
import boto3

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '...'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '...'

s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
                         aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                         aws_secret_access_key= AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
bucket_name = '...'
prefix = '...'

# List all objects within a S3 bucket path
response = s3_client.list_objects(Bucket = bucket_name, Prefix = prefix)
for file in response['Contents']:
    name = file['Key'].rsplit('/', 1)
    print name
```

After the execution I see:

```
1909132317.mp4
1909151647.mp4
...
```

So, I have an access to the videos. How can I download them to the local folder in my Mac? Please, help me.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40975060/download-a-binary-file-using-python-requests-module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`download_file()`](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_file) method to download the objects,

```
response = s3_client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=prefix)
for file in response['Contents']:
    name = file['Key'].rsplit('/', 1)
    s3_client.download_file(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=file['Key'], Filename='/localpath/'+name)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have the following error: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/localpath/test.afA18f1e' . How can I fix that?

Comment: @petrush Replace /localpath/ with your actual download path in Mac like `/Users/username/Downloads/`